# Assign column names in list of dataframes with NA values

Tags: r

I'm working with stocks data and I'm trying to get the imediate previous trading day to know what was the closing price and other info. My code so far only get the previous day, so it doesn't work properly on monday because it searches for info on sunday (not an active day for stocks).

For replication:

```
library(quantmod)

list_symbols_sample <- c("GLBS", "SBOT", "ACHV", "TTNP", "AVCO", "CCCL")

research_days_sample <- structure(c(17966, 17963, 17949, 17928, 17924, 17898), class = "Date")

stocks_df_sample <- lapply(list_symbols_sample, function(x) tryCatch(getSymbols(x, auto.assign = FALSE),error = function(e) { }))
```

This is the code that I'm using and its outcome:

```
stocks_OHLCV_previous_day <- list()

for (i in 1:3) {
    trade_date_temp <- as.Date(research_days[i]-1)
    OHLCV_temp <- stocks_df_sample[[i]][trade_date_temp]
    stocks_OHLCV_previous_day[[i]] <- data.frame(OHLCV_temp)
}

stocks_OHLCV_previous_day
[[1]]
[1] GLBS.Open     GLBS.High     GLBS.Low      GLBS.Close    GLBS.Volume   GLBS.Adjusted

    <0 linhas> (ou row.names de comprimento 0)

    [[2]]
               SBOT.Open SBOT.High SBOT.Low SBOT.Close SBOT.Volume SBOT.Adjusted
    2019-03-07      1.29      1.29     1.05        1.2       54300           1.2

    [[3]]
               ACHV.Open ACHV.High ACHV.Low ACHV.Close ACHV.Volume ACHV.Adjusted
    2019-02-21      1.58      1.82     1.55       1.79      145500          1.79
```

And that's what I need:

```
stocks_OHLCV_previous_day
        [[1]]
        [1]          GLBS.Open GLBS.High GLBS.Low GLBS.Close GLBS.Volume GLBS.Adjusted
        2019-03-08      3.34      5.34     3.25       4.44     2941900          4.44

        [[2]]
                   SBOT.Open SBOT.High SBOT.Low SBOT.Close SBOT.Volume SBOT.Adjusted
        2019-03-07      1.29      1.29     1.05        1.2       54300           1.2

        [[3]]
                   ACHV.Open ACHV.High ACHV.Low ACHV.Close ACHV.Volume ACHV.Adjusted
        2019-02-21      1.58      1.82     1.55       1.79      145500          1.79
```

Any tips on how to solve this?

Comment: I will have a look into it. It's the first time I'm using dput(). I used dput in research_days_sample

Comment: I see now, I forgot to close the loop with }.

Comment: I also changed the loop from (i in 1:6) to (i in 1:3), so the outcome is the same as in the question

Comment: When I run the third line I get warning messages: `Warning messages:
1: TTNP contains missing values. Some functions will not work if objects contain missing values in the middle of the series. Consider using na.omit(), na.approx(), na.fill(), etc to remove or replace them. 
2: AVCO contains missing values. Some functions will not work if objects contain missing values in the middle of the series. Consider using na.omit(), na.approx(), na.fill(), etc to remove or replace them.`

Comment: You can ignore that. You can even try running the data yourself. `stocks_df_sample[[4]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution using the `bizdays` and `lubridate` packages. For `bizdays` documentation, go to https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bizdays/bizdays.pdf.

You'll need to create a calendar for your country. I think there are several pre-installed in the `bizdays` package but I didn't check. The one used in the documentation is for Brazil so that's the one I used.

To solve this, I changed the first line of your loop only.

```
library(bizdays)
library(lubridate)

cal <- create.calendar("Brazil/ANBIMA", holidaysANBIMA, weekdays=c("saturday", "sunday"))

for (i in 1:3){
  trade_date_temp <- adjust.previous((research_days_sample %m-% days(1)), cal)[i]
  OHLCV_temp <- stocks_df_sample[[i]][trade_date_temp]
  stocks_OHLCV_previous_day[[i]] <- data.frame(OHLCV_temp)}
> stocks_OHLCV_previous_day
[[1]]
           GLBS.Open GLBS.High GLBS.Low GLBS.Close GLBS.Volume GLBS.Adjusted
2019-03-08      3.34      5.34     3.25       4.44     2941900          4.44

[[2]]
           SBOT.Open SBOT.High SBOT.Low SBOT.Close SBOT.Volume SBOT.Adjusted
2019-03-07      1.29      1.29     1.05        1.2       54300           1.2

[[3]]
           ACHV.Open ACHV.High ACHV.Low ACHV.Close ACHV.Volume ACHV.Adjusted
2019-02-21      1.58      1.82     1.55       1.79      145500          1.79
```